# Unable to Launch chrome (version 67) window 7 64 bit

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Not able to launch my chrome browser(version 67) , please refer below mentioned code and screenshot

```
package FirstPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class FirstClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\XY56082\\Desktop\\sel\\hromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        //FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // Open Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // Close browser
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: So far there is no screenshot, so we cannot help you. Is there any error message?

Comment: @KushalSharma Update the question with your binary details and the error stack trace.

Comment: @f1sh Please don't encourage screenshots as interpreting _HTML_ and debugging error stacktrace becomes difficult.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should change your driver to: 
chromedriver-2.35.exe

with chrome 67 it is the perfect driver.
I am using selenium 3.8.1 in maven.

Hope that helps you.